# Showing that a map defined using the dual is a bounded linear operator from X' into X'

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I have trouble answering the second part of the following exercise. Any help would be appreciated!

Let $(X, \| \cdot \|)$ be a reflexive Banach space. Let $\{ T_n \}_{n = 1}^\infty$ be a sequence of bounded linear operators from $X$ into $X$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(T_n x)$ exists for all $f \in X'$ and all $x \in X$.

(a) Show that $\sup_{n} \|T_n' \| < + \infty$

(b) Show that the map $S$ defined by $(Sf)(x) := \lim_{n \to \infty} (T_n'f)(x)$ is a bounded linear operator from $X'$ into $X'$.

What I've done so far:

(a): I have done this using the Uniform Boundedness Principle twice after first showing that $\sup_n \| T_n' (f)(x) \| < + \infty$

(b): I think that $\displaystyle \sup_n\|T_n' \|$ would make a good bound since we have just seen that it is finite, but I have not succeeded in proving that so far...

Thank you very much for any hints you can offer me!

Comment: You mean $\sup\limits_n \lVert T_n'\rVert$ in (b), presumably. Well, for every $x$ and $f$, you have $\lvert S(f)(x)\rvert = \lim \lvert T_n'(f)(x)\rvert \leqslant \limsup \lVert T_n'\rVert\cdot \lVert f\rVert \cdot \lVert x\rVert$.

Comment: What is $T_n'$?

Comment: @copper.hat $T_n':X' \to X'$ is the dual operator of $T_n$, given by $T_n'(f)(x) = f(T_nx)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I'm not entirely sure what you mean.. Does your statement imply that $\| S(f)(x) \| \leq \limsup \|T_n'\| \cdot \|f \| \cdot \|x\|$, since $\| S(f)(x) \| = \sup\{ |S(f)(x)|: \|x \| \leq 1 \}$ ?

Comment: You have a bound for $\lvert S(f)(x) \rvert$. Let $x$ range over the unit ball or unit sphere of $X$. That gives you a bound on $\lVert S(f)\rVert$. Let $f$ range over the unit ball/sphere of $X'$ to get a bound on $\lVert S\rVert$.

Comment: @DanielFischer This is probably wrong but: we have a bound for $|S(f)(x)|$ so $\|S(f)(x) \| = \sup\{|S(f)(x)|\}$ is also bounded for all $f \in X'$ and $x \in X$. Then applying the uniform boundedness principle two times we can show that $\|S\|< + \infty$. We can then take $\|S \|$ as a bound.

Comment: Let $N = \limsup \lVert T_n'\rVert$ (you could also take $\sup \lVert T_n'\rVert$, that's not important). You have shown $N < \infty$. Also, for all $x\in X, f \in X'$, you have $\lvert S(f)(x)\rvert \leqslant N\lVert f\rVert \cdot \lVert x\rVert$. That immediately implies $\lVert S(f)\rVert \leqslant N\lVert f\rVert$ for all $f\in X'$, and that alone implies that $S$ is continuous with $\lVert S\rVert \leqslant N$. You don't need any further application of Banach-Steinhaus.

Comment: @DanielFischer I see it now! Thanks, Daniel, you're a lifesaver! I'm interested though, you answered another question of mine also in the comments, why don't you make answers so I can at least repay you with some reputation?

Comment: The reputation isn't important once you have enough to have all privileges you deem important. I often don't write an answer because at that moment, I don't have the time, or I give a hint in a comment trying to help the asker find the solution him/herself. When it works, that's much better than just serving a complete answer immediately. I'll write an answer here now to get it from the "unanswered" list. (And if you haven't yet got an answer-answer on the other one, if I find it, I may also write one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have shown that $A := \sup\limits_n \lVert T_n'\rVert < \infty$, you have a known bound on $S(f)(x)$ for every $x\in X$ and $f\in X'$, namely

$$\lvert S(f)(x)\rvert = \lim_{n\to\infty} \lvert T_n'(f)(x)\rvert \leqslant \limsup_{n\to\infty} \lVert T_n'(f)\rVert\cdot \lVert x\rVert \leqslant \limsup_{n\to\infty} \lVert T_n'\rVert\cdot \lVert f\rVert\cdot \lVert x\rVert.$$

From $\lvert S(f)(x)\rvert \leqslant N\lVert f\rVert\cdot \lVert x\rVert$, we deduce by the definition of the norm on $X'$ that $\lVert S(f)\rVert \leqslant N\cdot \lVert f\rVert$, and this in turn shows that $S$ is a continuous (bounded) operator on $X'$ with $\lVert S\rVert \leqslant N$.